# How to host two app .NET API & Laravel in Nginx (Ubuntu)?

Tags: asp.net, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to host an API developed using .NET 7 for a flutter app on an Ubuntu server using Ngnix, within the same server I want to host the Admin Panel for that API to manage the database, I configured everything correct the two app are running fine, but the problem is that, they both can't run on the same time, when I set my actual IP address as a `server_name` in the Nginvconfiguration file for one of the apps, it becomes the only one it works, but when I but the same `server_name` for both apps, the Laravel takes over the API and shows Laravel error `404 - NOT Found`, I want to run the API and Laravel `in sync` with each other.

Here is my config for both apps:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name 65.2*.***.***;
    root /var/www/API;
    location / {
    
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }   
    
}
```

Laravel Admin Panel

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/adminPanel

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 65.2*.***.***;
    root /var/www/adminPanel/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.php;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I need to find a solution for this, it has been two months working on fixing this issue.

Comment: Maybe u can use domain name with subdomains?

Comment: Well you cant just put 2 applications under the same ip+port and same subdirectory. What should NGINX do when it gets a requests? Just randomly select to which application it should proxy the request?
One way would be to use 2 different ports for the applications, an other option would be to use different subdirectories (laravel listens on `/` and the api on `/api`). But I dont know how the current configuration should work.